# Задача на С удаление из файла

Tags: c

Задание заключается в том, что в файле должны остаться слова, в которых есть хоть одна буква "а" и ни одной буквы "е". Слова под мою выборку определяются правильно, но я не знаю как удалить их из файла. Мой код:

```
    #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #define N 32

    int
    main ()
     {
     FILE *fp, *fp2;
     char buffer[N];
     int count = 0;
     char *word = NULL;
    if ((fp = fopen ("text.txt", "r")) == NULL)
    {
      printf ("Error read file");
      exit (0);
    }

    while (!feof (fp))
    {
      count = 0;
      fgets (buffer, N, fp);

      for (int i = 0; i < strlen (buffer); i++)
    {

      if (buffer[i] != '\n')
        {
          count++;
        }
      if (buffer[i] == '\n')
        {


          word = (char *) malloc ((count + 1) * sizeof (char));
          for (int j = 0; j < count + 1; j++)
        {
          word[j] = buffer[(i - count) + j];

        }
          word[count] = '\0';

          char *ptr = strchr (word, 'a');
          char *ptr2 = strchr (word, 'e');
          if (ptr == NULL && ptr2 != NULL)
        {
          puts (word);
        }
          else
        continue;

        }
    }
    }


  fclose (fp);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: *не знаю как удалить их из файла* Полностью перезаписать файл (или удалить и записать новую версию).

Comment: @Akina перезаписать файл с учетом вот этих условий с буквами а и е

Comment: Вы сказали, что "Слова под мою выборку определяются правильно". Вот эти правильно определённые и отобранные слова и записывайте в новый файл.

Comment: @Akina мне нужно работать только с одним файлом

Comment: Прочитайте содержимое файла, закройте файл, отфильтруйте слова, откройте тот же файл на запись, запишите в него отфильтрованные слова.

Comment: @nevilad 20 Я понимаю как это сделать только на словах, поэтому обратился сюда

Answer (score 1):

Вот так это можно сделать, суть объяснена в комментариях:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 32

void HandleWord(const char* pWordBegin, int wordSize, FILE *fp)
{
  //memchr позволяет указать длину, не нужно чтобы буфер заканчивался нулями.
  //Т.е. можно искать в оригинальном буфере и не надо делать копию слов.
  if (memchr(pWordBegin, 'a', wordSize) &&
      !memchr(pWordBegin, 'e', wordSize))
  {
    fwrite(pWordBegin, 1, wordSize, fp);

    //В оригинале писали в строку завершающий ноль:
    //word[count] = '\0';
    //Этот код запишет строки так, как они были разделены в оригинальном
    //файле - переводом строки или концом файла.
  }
}

int main()
{
  FILE *fp;
  char* fileData;
  long int fSize;
  size_t readSize;
  int wordBegin;

  //Открываем файл на чтение
  if ((fp = fopen("text.txt", "rb")) == NULL)
  {
    printf("Error open file for reading");
    exit(0);
  }

  //Получим размер файла
  fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
  fSize = ftell(fp);
  fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);

  //Выделим буфер под содержимое файла
  fileData = (char*)malloc(fSize);
  if (!fileData)
  {
    printf("Error allocate %lu bytes", fSize);
    exit(0);
  }

  //Считаем содержимое файла
  readSize = fread(fileData, 1, fSize, fp);
  if( readSize != fSize)
  {
    printf("Error reading %lu bytes, read only %zu bytes", fSize, readSize);
    exit(0);
  }
  //Закрываем файл
  fclose(fp);

  //Открываем тот же файл на запись
  if ((fp = fopen("text.txt", "wb")) == NULL)
  {
    printf("Error open file for writing");
    exit(0);
  }

  //В оригинале читали строки размером не более 32 и через fgets, т.е. до следующего перевода
  //каретки или конца файла. Поэтому проходим по символам строки в поиске '\n'.
  wordBegin = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < fSize; i++)
  {
    if (fileData[i] == '\n')
    {
      HandleWord(&fileData[wordBegin], i - wordBegin + 1, fp);
      wordBegin = i + 1;
    }
  }

  //Обработка последнего слова, которое может не завершаться переводом строки.
  if (wordBegin < fSize)
    HandleWord(&fileData[wordBegin], fSize - wordBegin, fp);

  //Закрываем файл
  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```